# JQuery Closing Button Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five `buttons` with bootstrap `close` , i added `onclick` Event handler to `alert()` next sibiling text. Problem is it shows `alert()` on first close button only.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cz57mge/

```
<script>
    $("#closenotify").click(function(){
        alert($(this).next().text());
    });
</script>
```

I'm newbiew to JQuery let me know what am i missing here?

Thanks

Comment: `id` **must be unique.** You cannot have more than one element with any given id value in the whole page. Change `id` to `class` and `$("#closenotify")` to `$(".closenotify")` .

Comment: Thanks,I understood, using `class="closenotify close"`  solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using an ID, which is unique, so jQuery stops at the first one it finds. Go ahead and change your code to use a class and it will work. You've already added a `close` class to each, so just change it to the following.

On a side note, you've got a couple extra closing `div` tags in your jsFiddle.

#### Solution

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

#### Working Demo

```js
$(".close").click(function(){
    alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

```css
.alert-purple { border-color: #694D9F;background: #694D9F;color: #fff; }
.alert-info-alt { border-color: #B4E1E4;background: #81c7e1;color: #fff; }
.alert-danger-alt { border-color: #B63E5A;background: #E26868;color: #fff; }
.alert-warning-alt { border-color: #F3F3EB;background: #E9CEAC;color: #fff; }
.alert-success-alt { border-color: #19B99A;background: #20A286;color: #fff; }
.glyphicon { margin-right:10px; }
.alert a {color: gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-purple alert-dismissable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
        <button type="button" id="closenotify" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button><strong>sagsagsagsagsag</strong> 
    </div>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-purple alert-dismissable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
        <button type="button" id="closenotify" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button><strong>fdsggsdgsdgsdg</strong> 
    </div>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-purple alert-dismissable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
        <button type="button" id="closenotify" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button><strong>sgaasgsagsaggasg</strong> 
    </div>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-purple alert-dismissable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
        <button type="button" id="closenotify" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button><strong>This is a test nigga</strong> 
    </div>
        </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="alert alert-purple alert-dismissable">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
        <button type="button" id="closenotify" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button><strong>This is a test nigga</strong> 
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id